# Not populating dropdownlist inside $.each

Tags: jquery

I have such code:

```
var options = $("#drop");
$.getJSON("/services.asmx/GetResults", params, function (result) {

        $.each(result, function () {
            //alert(this.Name) works!    
            options.append($("<option />").text("test"));  
        });

    });
//options.append($("<option />").text("test"));  Works!
```

and it's not appending my dropdownlist. If I move that line out of getJSON method, it works. I debugged and all data returned (result) is correct, there are no errors. Originally I want to add this.Name instead of "test", but even simple string does not append.. What's wrong here?

UPDATE: I just figured out, that I am using jquery CHOSEN plugin, which converts option tags to li. I bet that's a problem. I still didn't solve the issue and wonder why it works only outside service call, but not inside.. Thank you for your answers!!!

Comment: What is the output of result?

Comment: JSON: [{"ID":6,"Name":"Test"}{"ID":3,"Name":"Test2"}]  sorry if this example output format is invalid, wrote a simple version of that..

Comment: Have you verified the JSON is valid and does not contain any errors?  Try JSONLint if you haven't already.

Comment: yap, just did and it's valid. It's simple array of objects.

Comment: @StewieGriffin: What type of element is `#drop`

Comment: What do you get if you replace alert(this.Name) with alert(options.length) ?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: <select id="drop">

Comment: @Dean North: I get 1, lots of 1, as it's in the loop :)

Comment: Is your code any different from this: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/3Mhbn/ ?

Comment: different only that I have service call. The rest is the same..

Comment: @Stewie: I'd say that narrows down the issue, then, eh?!

Comment: @Tomalak: Agreed, it must be a problem with the data coming back

Comment: I disagree, if his alert was showing inside the loop and he isnt doing anything with the data (he is using "test" in his example) then it has nothing to do with the actual data coming back. It is more likely due to the browser changing the DOM on a separate thread because of the ajax callback.

Comment: It was my plugin (chosen). I had to include a call to it's js right after service call. A plugin converts options tag to li, that's why it didnt work. I appreciate all your responses !!!

Comment: yea, now I hate, when I solve it and need to pick a correct answer while you all are technically right :)

Comment: @Stewie: You can post your _own_ answer, explaining what the _real_ problem was, and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and it works for me. The only thing I could think of is that you selector for the dropdown is incorrect. You say:

```
var options = $("#drop");
```

But I notice that you are calling an ASMX Web service. Is your dropdown list an ASP.NET DropDownList? If it's an ASP.NET DropDownList, your markup might look something like:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drop">
```

When this gets rendered on the client-side, the ID is no longer *drop*. It would be more like *ParentControlID_drop*.

Double-check your selector.

Comment: I call service just to get a data, but my Dropdown is in html/js. IDs are correct..

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting this problem only in IE?

After the loop alert(options.html()) you will probably find that the html looks correct but it isnt updated on the page. there are some DOM caching issues in some browsers which cache DOM changes until a property is read that requires a render.

I have fixed this before by hiding and showing the dropdown after populating it. It sounds crazy, but it is worth a try.

*edit: might have been a width change rather than a hide/show*

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with a jquery Chosen plugin, which grabs a standard dropdownlist and turns to  and

tags instead of  . FYI it also strips out value and other attributes. I had to work on Chosen.js script to put it back and make it work.

[Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)